# How to display a drop-down list option/selection menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have been working on this for few hours and got stuck, so
how to get menu selection using database, db using model `ZigZagRotation`?

```
<%= form_for([@user, @user.calories_journals.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.label :cj_date, "Date Begins:" %>
  <%= f.text_field :cj_date %>
  <%= f.label :no_of_cycles, "Number of Cycles:" %>
  <%= f.text_field :no_of_cycles %>      
  <%= f.label :zig_zag_type, "Zig Zag Rotation Type:" %>
  <%= f.select :zig_zag_type, ZigZagRotation.all.collect {|z| [z.title, z.id ] } %> 
  <%= f.submit "Generate Calories Journals", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The line below shows empty details in menu selection box instead of populated list.

```
<%= f.select :zig_zag_type, ZigZagRotation.all.collect {|z| [z.title, z.id ] } %>
```

`:zig_zag_type` is `attr_accessible` under `ZigZagRotation` model and once it is selected I wish the value to be stored in `:id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are working with two different and related models (`ZigZagRotation` and `AnotherModel` for example).

If you want to display the `zig_zag_type` attribute and save its `id` in the `AnotherModel` foreign key (`zig_zag_id` for example), creating the relationship between them, you can do something like the below:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:zig_zag_id, ZigZagRotation.all, :id, :zig_zag_type , {:include_blank => 'Select Type'} ) %>
```

You can find more information [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select).
I hope it helps...

Comment: Yes, it is very helpful.  More clearer than using documentation you gave me.  Sometimes, documentation can be difficult to understand. Thank you.

Comment: I am glad I could help :).. and I agree about the documentation, sometimes it is very difficult to understand...